# F# and Series, How to write a Series.choose?

Tags: f#, deedle

I have decided to write a Series.choose function, similar to the one we have on Seq and I wanted to know if you think it is the best way to write it, going back to a Seq as there is a function there.

```
let choose (f: 'K * 'V -> ('K * 'U) option) (e : Series<'K,'V>) =
        e |> Series.map (fun k v -> k, v)
          |> Series.values
          |> (Seq.choose f)
          |> Series.ofValues
          |> Series.map (fun _ v -> snd v)
          |> Series.indexWith (e |> Series.keys)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mapAll`](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/SeriesModule.fs#L467) is nearly what you need, it just has a slightly different signature (and in particular, can't change the keys). If you do need to change the keys, it becomes more difficult but still shouldn't require going via `Seq`. It also depends on how you want to deal with missing values in `e`.

Untested (because I don't have Visual Studio here), and assumes `e` has no missing values, but should give the idea:

```
let choose (f: 'K * 'V -> ('K * 'U) option) (e : Series<'K,'V>) =
    e |> Series.mapAll (fun k (Some v) -> f (k, v)) // Series<'K, ('K, 'U)> 
      |> Series.dropMissing // drops cases where f returned None
      |> fun e1 -> e1.SelectKeys (fun kvp -> fst kvp.Value.Value) // changes the keys to the ones f returned
      |> Series.mapValues snd // removes the keys from the values
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be: |> fun e1 -> e1.SelectKeys (fun kvp -> fst kvp.Value.Value). I guess that this I drop all missing values for the instruction just above, I end up in a situation where kvp.Value.Value will never return the exception for missing value. Am I right?

Comment: Ah right, because `kvp` is `KeyValuePair<'K, OptionalValue<('K, 'U)>>` and not `KeyValuePair<'K, ('K, 'U)>`.

Comment: Also, if you change the keys you can allow changing their type as well. Code doesn't even need to change except for `f`'s type.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I wrote for my "Toolbox". Just in case it saves time to someone in the future...

```
    /// Choose only on values keeping the same keys
    let chooseV (f: 'V -> 'U option) (e : Series<'K,'V>) =
        e |> Series.mapAll (fun _ (Some v) -> f v)
          |> Series.dropMissing

    /// Choose on both keys and values, changing the keys to type 'J
    let chooseKV (f: 'K * 'V -> ('J * 'U) option) (e : Series<'K,'V>) =
        e |> Series.mapAll (fun k (Some v) -> f (k, v))
          |> Series.dropMissing
          |> fun e1 -> e1.SelectKeys (fun kvp -> fst kvp.Value.Value)
          |> Series.mapValues snd

    /// Choose on just the values using the keys in the function
    let choose (f: 'K * 'V -> ('K * 'U) option) (e : Series<'K,'V>) =
        e |> Series.mapAll (fun k (Some v) -> f (k, v))
          |> Series.dropMissing
          |> Series.mapValues snd
```